# Adding columns that contains nulls (no value) in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

i have a requirement here i we need to add a checksum(absolute sum) value in the file to make sure about data validity .Issue is that this requirement is for different files which are different in structure and data domains . 
My current code works fine if the column contains numeric values

```
  ABOSULTE_COUNT=$(cat $Source_file | cut-d '|' -f $absolute_column_number | paste -sd+ | bc -1)
```

This code works fine if data is present but have issues if a row does not contain value .

My current scenario are below . i need a single computation formula for all

1.All rows in the column contain data value .
2.Few rows value are missing rest contain numeric value , missing information will mean 0 for our calculation , 0 value will not be present in the file 
3.All rows have missing information , same as case 2 , 0 will result for this case .

Answer (score 0):

change the missing values to 0 with `sed`

```
cut-d '|' -f $absolute_column_number | sed -e 's/^$/0/' | paste -sd+
```